# Boolean on_change event error Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have an on_change function. The purpose of this on_change is to see when the boolean was last changed. (bool=boolean, datenow=datetime):

```
@api.onchange('bool')
def onchange_bool(self):
    self.datenow=datetime.datetime.now()
```

When I call it(Press the boolean button) in my `res.partner` I get an error: `ValueError: "name 'partner_id' is not defined" while evaluating '[partner_id]'` Any ideas/pointers?

EDIT the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 537, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 574, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 310, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 307, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 803, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 403, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/service_logger/service_logger.py", line 97, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/service_logger/service_logger.py", line 83, in _call_kw
    res = super(LoggerDataSet, self)._call_kw(model, method, args, kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 256, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 387, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5957, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 5857, in _onchange_eval
    params = eval("[%s]" % params, global_vars, field_vars)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/tools/safe_eval.py", line 314, in safe_eval
    return eval(c, globals_dict, locals_dict)
  File "", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: "name 'partner_id' is not defined" while evaluating
'[partner_id]'
```

Comment: What does the decorator do? also are you sure the exception occurs here?

Comment: "This decorator will trigger the call to the decorated function if any of the fields specified in the decorator is changed in the form:" from the [Odoo API page](http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.org/en/latest/decorator.html) and I try to change the bool field in my form.